# Manipulate Material Elements of Child Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a set of 3D models and each has its own material elements. One model has all elements in a mesh renderer and its easy for me to make changes to each elements as seen below:

[image]

Code used to make changes

```
public Renderer[] rend;

    rend[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SelectedBall")].materials[0].color = currentcolor;
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SelectedBall") == 1)
    {
        rend[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SelectedBall")].materials[0].color = Color.white;
        rend[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SelectedBall")].materials[1].color = currentcolor;
        rend[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SelectedBall")].materials[2].color = currentcolor;
        rend[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SelectedBall")].materials[3].color = currentcolor;
    }
```

I have a second model with 2 child objects, each with its own elements.

[image]

The challenge I am facing is if I use same code above, it only affects "Cylinder001" elements.

How do I access the Sphere003 elements and make changes as well in one code.

Thanks

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: you are using the same name for both material

Comment: not getting any errors. the only issue is the color changes i make to cylinder001 does not affect sphere003. See image https://snag.gy/4klcWb.jpg, the cylinder will change color but the dot spheres still remains red.

What you mean same name for both materials?

Comment: name of the material is Material #25

Comment: yes both using same name

Comment: change material name os Sphere003 and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand why there is a renderer array exactly or if you use it to access all mesh renderers for all your models but this piece of code might help to solve the issue for all objects:

```
    for (int i = 0; i< gameObject.transform.childCount;i++)
    {
       rend = gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
       rend.materials[0].color = Color.white;
       for(int j = 1; j<rend.materials.Length;j++)
        {
            rend.materials[j].color = currentcolor;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The info provided did give me idea on how to access the child element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to traverse the transform tree, for example to get sibling components (I understand that you want to affect the MeshRenderer of a sibling object) you can use transform.parent to move a level up.

```
GameObject parentGameObject=transform.parent.gameObject;
MeshRenderer[] allMeshRenderers=parentGameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
```

Then you could iterate through the renderers and change colors/materials as you will